# What keyboard shortcuts exist for navigating the window selection mode of the Gnome Shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gnome-shell

I've been playing around with the Gnome Shell on my netbook for a week or so and I like the extra space it affords me. However I wonder if I'm missing some keyboard shortcuts when switching between views?

When I activate selection mode with the  key is there any way to navigate to another window by keyboard alone? Currently I have to raise my hands off the keyboard to select a window on the mousepad or use the less efficient Alt-Tab approach.

If I start typing the integrated search just seems to search the list of installed apps. It would be nice if I could make it search the window titles. Is this something I'd need to script up myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this functionality is solved with an extension. The example Gnome Shell extensions [http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions] include one for modifying the overview window. The modification allows you to select a window with Alt-.

I'm sure more elaborate approaches are possible.